# Add values from reactive object to existing data frame as column

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to using Shiny and having some problems with adding reactive values to an existing data frame.

I have a reactive object called CalculatedDistance which calculates a distance when the input on the shiny app is changed. I am trying to add the calculated distances in this object to a new column in the data frame but receive the following error message:

`Error in CalculatedDistance[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

The following code works fine until I try to add the values to the new column.

```
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used

alldata <- iris

#adds a column of a unique ID for each row
alldata$ID <- 1:nrow(alldata)

# UI

ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("Explorer"),
fluidRow(
       wellPanel(
         numericInput(inputId = "UserPetalLength", label="Input Petal Length", value = 0, step = 0.1),
         numericInput(inputId = "UserPetalWidth", label="Input Petal Width", value = 0, step = 0.1)),
         tableOutput('Table')
))

#SERVER
server<-function(input,output,session)
{
 CalculatedDistance<- reactive({
    calculatedDistance <- sqrt((alldata$Petal.Length-input$UserPetalLength)^2 + (alldata$Petal.Width-input$UserPetalWidth)^2)
  })

 alldata$distance<- NA
 nRows <- nrow(alldata)
 for (i in 1:nRows)
 {
   alldata$distance[i]= CalculatedDistance[i]
 }
 output$Table = renderTable(alldata)

}


#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I think you missed a set of parenthesis in `server`: `alldata$distance[i]= CalculatedDistance()[i]` may work

Comment: You should also probably wrap that section in a `reactive` so that it updates every time the `UserPetalLength` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me; I made a few changes in `server` to make it work.

- Wrapped the add to dataframe part in a reactive environment
- The loop you have isn't necessary, since `CalculatedDistance` returns a vector, we can add that on to the dataframe easily
- Added a pair of `{}` in the `output$Table`
- Convert the dataframe to a datatable

---

```
    #server.R


    shinyServer(function(input,output,session)
    {
      CalculatedDistance<- reactive({
        calculatedDistance <- sqrt((alldata$Petal.Length-input$UserPetalLength)^2 + (alldata$Petal.Width-input$UserPetalWidth)^2)
        calculatedDistance
      })

      add_to_df <- reactive({
        alldata$distance<- NA
        nRows <- nrow(alldata)
        alldata$distance <- CalculatedDistance()

        alldata

      })

      output$Table <- renderTable({
        data.table(add_to_df())

      })

    })
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! Had to install the data.table package but after that everything is good!